# Dont insert document if already exists in Elasticsearch with Golang

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I am new to golang and I'm struggling in inserting new documents with the same id in Elasticsearch. Until now I can insert the document correctly in the index, but if the document's id is repeated, the timestamp updates (because is the only thing that is changing). However, what I am looking to do is not to update the document, in other words, do nothing at all.

In the case of Python, to accomplish this I do the following thing:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
            [elastic_url],
            http_auth=(elastic_user, elastic_password),
            verify_certs=True,
        )

return es.create(index=index_name, id=document_id, body=data, ignore=409)
```

And in golang I'm using the following code:

```
req := esapi.IndexRequest{
            Index:      "test_index",
            DocumentID: "2",
            Body:       strings.NewReader(data),
            Refresh:    "false",
        }

        
res, err := req.Do(ctx, es)
```

It would be awesome some help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you can check the existence of the document by its ID before you're doing the insert operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API available in `esapi` for checking existence of a document id in a particular index.

[ExistRequest](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/esapi#ExistsRequest) - By checking the status code of the response from this request we can confirm whether that document id is present or not (200 if present and 404 if not present)

```
// prepare existence checking request
req := esapi.ExistsRequest{
    Index:      index,
    DocumentID: id,
}

// send existence checking request
// client here is *elastic.Client
ctx := context.Background()
resp, err := req.Do(ctx, client)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

status := resp.StatusCode
if status == 200 {
    fmt.Println("Exist")
} else if status == 404 {
    fmt.Println("Not found")
}
```